# how compile works when we use concating two string object in java

Tags: java

```
 class Simple{  
     public static void main(String args[]){  
         String s="Sachin"+" Tendulkar";  
         System.out.println(s);//Sachin Tendulkar  
     }  
 }
```

The compiler transforms this to:

```
    String s = (new StringBuilder()).append("Sachin").append(" Tendulkar").toString();
```

what is mean by last line?

Comment: Actually, it won't transform it to that at all. (At least not the Oracle compiler.)

Comment: With string literals I don't think the compiler has to use a StringBuilder. Now if you concatenated `args` into one String it would look something like that. It means the JVM will use a StringBuilder to perform String concatenation, since Java String(s) are immutable.

Comment: Like for your String taken :D

Answer (score 3):

Java compiler will just concat this two string at compile time and it would result into following instructions

for code

```
public class StringConcatInspection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Sachin" + " Tendulkar";
    }
}
```

it would compile to

```
  Last modified Jul 9, 2014; size 473 bytes
  MD5 checksum 5238429068ccae4ec199f4af970ad46e
  Compiled from "StringConcatInspection.java"
public class StringConcatInspection
  SourceFile: "StringConcatInspection.java"
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #4.#20         //  java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = String             #21            //  Sachin Tendulkar
   #3 = Class              #22            //  StringConcatInspection
   #4 = Class              #23            //  java/lang/Object
   #5 = Utf8               <init>
   #6 = Utf8               ()V
   #7 = Utf8               Code
   #8 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
   #9 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
  #10 = Utf8               this
  #11 = Utf8               LStringConcatInspection;
  #12 = Utf8               main
  #13 = Utf8               ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #14 = Utf8               args
  #15 = Utf8               [Ljava/lang/String;
  #16 = Utf8               s
  #17 = Utf8               Ljava/lang/String;
  #18 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #19 = Utf8               StringConcatInspection.java
  #20 = NameAndType        #5:#6          //  "<init>":()V
  #21 = Utf8               Sachin Tendulkar
  #22 = Utf8               StringConcatInspection
  #23 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
{
  public StringConcatInspection();
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0       
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return        
      LineNumberTable:
        line 4: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               0       5     0  this   LStringConcatInspection;

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: ldc           #2                  // String Sachin Tendulkar
         2: astore_1      
         3: return        
      LineNumberTable:
        line 6: 0
        line 7: 3
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               0       4     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
               3       1     1     s   Ljava/lang/String;
}
```

Compiler version: 1.7.0_60-ea

<sub>respect for sachin</sub>

Comment: If you use javap -v, it will dump out the constant pool, and you can see how javac represents this in the constant pool (rather than just in the comments) next to the bytecodes.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you're asking about how using StringBuilder differs from normal String concatenation (rather than some compiler/IDE optimisation).

Strings in Java are immutable, meaning that once they're created they cannot be modified. Therefore when you perform some operation on a given string - such as `String.concat()` or `String.replaceAll()` which look on first glance that they will alter the string's internal state - you are in fact creating a new string object which is derived from the original immutable object, and as such that has to be saved somewhere.

```
String example = "This is a test ";
example = example.trim(); // "This is a test"
```

Often such operations aren't terribly expensive but if you have to due a lot of String modification then using this approach can end up being very costly with all the object creation.

The alternative is to use a class like StringBuilder which represents mutable character sequence. With this class it is possible to modify the instance itself. So concatenation via the 'StringBuilder.append()' method is must cheaper in CPU/memory terms compared to 'String.concat()'. Of course, once you've finished constructing your StringBuilder you'll often want to get a normal String, hence its `toString()` method.

Another handy aspect of StringBuilder is that it uses [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) so that its methods returns itself and that allows you to chain calls in one line.

StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
   b.append("One");
   b.append("Two");
   b.append("Three").append("Four");

This can make certain things more readable, eg

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(user.getLastName()).append(", ").append(user.getFirstName());
// Better than mixing String concatenation
sb.append(user.getLastName() + ", " + user.getFirstName()); // Valid but defeats purpose of using StringBuilder
```

Answer (score 0):

When concatenating only string literals, the compiler should rewrite to just be the literals combined.

```
// source
String s="Sachin"+" Tendulkar";

// compiler rewrite
String s="Sachin Tendulkar";
```

However, if there is at least one non-constant, then my understanding is that a `StringBuilder` will be used to avoid creating temporary one-time-use objects that just make extra work for the garbage collector.

```
// source
String s = "Sachin"+" Tendulkar" + title;

// compiler rewrite (approximately)
String s = (new StringBuilder("Sachin Tendulkar")).append(title).toString();
```

Whether it passes the literal to the constructor or uses `.append` on both strings is something I don't know.  You can compile the code then try de-compiling it with `JAD` to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Java Language Specification, 3rd edition for Java SE 5, §15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.28):

> Compile-time constants of type String are always "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

From the same document, [§15.18.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.18.1):

> The result [of the String Concatenation Operator +] is a reference to a String object (newly created, **unless the expression is a compile-time constant expression (§15.28)**) that is the concatenation of the two operand strings.

Emphasis mine.

So, the Java specification has been requiring, since at least Java 5, that constants formed by concatenating constants are *interned strings*, and thus are optimized to constants directly (without evaluating the concatenation at runtime).

Note too that because this is a requirement of the specification, *all* compliant implementations must implement this interning behaviour; it is not simply an optimization that the Sun/Oracle Java implementation chooses to use.