# Java optimization of String

Tags: java

I've heard (can't find the source) that starting on Java 5 statements such as

`String a = "a" + "B" + "c";` were actually optimized by the compiler into `String a = "aBc";`

But I can't find it online.

Can you help a sister out?

Could you please reconsider marking my question as a duplicate? The question marked as dup actually is the behavior of the compiler, NOT the reference to the docs, which is my question about.

Also, my question asks when this behavior started, which is not addressed by the question marked as dup.

Comment: You want us to find the source of that statement?

Comment: Just for the record, I am not being lazy. I did spend a considerable amount of time and there are some references on the web, but I can't find a good source, such as a JSR doc, or an Oracle page.

Comment: @CindyLangdon: Did you try the language specification, and look for "constant"? Note that this was not new in Java 5. I believe it's been the case forever.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: That's not what the question is about though. It's about *compile-time* concatenation of constant strings.

Comment: Yes. I saw that, @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ, but there is also a native component for Strings. Also, the behavior I mentioned is an optimization for the VM, not of the source code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581824/does-java-compiler-include-string-constant-folding, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.28

Comment: @CindyLangdon Actually, it's a source code transformation. The VM has no clue that `a` was formed by the concatenation of several strings. It's all taken care of by the compiler. Unless that's what you meant by "optimization for the VM"?

Comment: I think the answer provided by @nneonneo is good enough. Would you like to post it? The second reference. The first one is not good.

Comment: @CindyLangdon: I would but this question is already marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I believe it's answered by http://stackoverflow.com/a/24660640/376366, with reference to the documentation.

Comment: @FernandoCorreia That is a reference to the doc. Not saying when that behavior started.